# how to define more than one table in a model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I have three tables in my table named "users", "role" and "user_meta". And i want to use these tables in my model named "User.php" to save the data. But the problem is that if i associate the other two tables with "users" table then cakephp asked for the plural form of the table. It means i have defined the table name as "role" and "user_meta" then cakephp asking for "roles" and "user_meta".

Now problem is that i cannot change my table name, I have use these table names.

Can anyone help me out to How to save data in the other tables?

Thanks,
Sunil Jindal

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have *one* model per table.

What you want to use is [Model::$useTable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) to change the table of the models.

Comment: What if i want to save data in more than one table in a model?

Comment: Read the book? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html It's all described there including examples.